# ASP.NET MVC Content pages is not showing in _layout template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to show the content pages (for example index.vbhtml) in my template (_layout.vbhtml) but it is not working. in plain html content pages it's working fine. 
i am not sure where i am getting wrong. Shots:≥≥≥
  [_layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWfDk.png)  [index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLVgN.png)  [out-true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRwN4.png)   [out-wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYgRf.png)

Comment: can you please add some code to review.

Comment: thanks, I attached screen shot

Comment: I sent _layout file Bellow 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved . The address of the scripts in the _layout file and in the link tags must start with / ~
like this:

```
href="~/dist/...."
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have anything in your ViewStart file that's designating layout?

Comment: I have not changed the file and its information is the same as the default

Comment: Can you post a shot of a page that shows how you're referring to the layout file?

Comment: I've posted above. First post (Index file)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing to add bellow code

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

place your code to review

Comment: i attached screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with the code _layout.vbhtml. Because when I replaced with another _layout, the problem was resolved. 
This is my _layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>صفحه شروع | کنترل پنل</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap rtl -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/rtl.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
    @RenderSection("scripts", False)

</head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Main Header -->
        <header class="main-header">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a href="index2.html" class="logo">
                <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
                <span class="logo-mini">پنل</span>
                <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
                <span class="logo-lg"><b>کنترل پنل مدیریت</b></span>
            </a>
            <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </a>


                <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                                <span class="hidden-xs">علیرضا حسینی زاده</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <!-- User image -->
                                <li class="user-header">
                                    <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                                    <p>
                                        علیرضا حسینی زاده
                                        <small>مدیریت کل سایت</small>
                                    </p>
                                </li>
                                <!-- Menu Body -->
                                <li class="user-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                            <a href="#">صفحه من</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                            <a href="#">فروش</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                            <a href="#">دوستان</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.row -->
                                </li>
                                <!-- Menu Footer-->
                                <li class="user-footer">
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">پروفایل</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">خروج</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <!-- right side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
        <aside class="main-sidebar">
            <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
            <section class="sidebar">

                <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="جستجو">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- /.search form -->
                <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
                <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
                    <li class="header">تیتر</li>
                    <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>لینک</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>لینک ۲</span></a></li>
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>چند سطحی</span>
                            <span class="pull-left-container">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-left"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">لینک سطح ۱</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">لینک سطح ۱</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
            </section>
            <!-- /.sidebar -->
        </aside>
        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1>
                    عنوان صفحه
                    <small>توضیحات</small>
                </h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> خانه</a></li>
                    <li class="active">صفحه</li>
                </ol>
            </section>
            <!-- Main content -->
            <section class="content container-fluid">
                <!--------------------------
                | Your Page Content Here |
                -------------------------->
                @RenderBody()

            </section>
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
        <!-- Main Footer -->
        <footer class="main-footer text-left">
            <strong>Copyleft &copy; 2014-2017 <a href="https://adminlte.io">Almsaeed Studio</a> & <a href="http://hosseinizadeh.ir/adminlte">Alireza Hosseinizadeh</a></strong>
        </footer>
        <!-- Control Sidebar -->
        <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
            <!-- Create the tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified control-sidebar-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#control-sidebar-home-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#control-sidebar-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <!-- Home tab content -->
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="control-sidebar-home-tab">
                    <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">فعالیت ها</h3>
                    <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;">
                                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-birthday-cake bg-red"></i>
                                <div class="menu-info">
                                    <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">تولد غلوم</h4>
                                    <p>۲۴ مرداد</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->
                    <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">پیشرفت کارها</h3>
                    <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;">
                                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                                    آپدیت لاراول
                                    <span class="pull-left-container">
                                        <span class="label label-danger pull-left">70%</span>
                                    </span>
                                </h4>
                                <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 70%"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.tab-pane -->
                <!-- Stats tab content -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-stats-tab">تب وضعیت</div>
                <!-- /.tab-pane -->
                <!-- Settings tab content -->
                <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
                    <form method="post">
                        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">تنظیمات عمومی</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                                گزارش کنترلر پنل
                                <input type="checkbox" class="pull-left" checked>
                            </label>
                            <p>
                                ثبت تمامی فعالیت های مدیران
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.form-group -->
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.tab-pane -->
            </div>
        </aside>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
        <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
        immediately after the control sidebar -->
        <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->
    <!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- jQuery 3 -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved . The address of the scripts in the _layout file and in the head tag must start with / ~
like this:
`href="~/dist/...."`